# Why does println not show up - Java

Tags: java, methods, printing, println

I am a newb with Java so don't bite me please.. 
I've made this method, but it will not show up in the console screen, why?

```
public class ADSopgave2K1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        }

        public void print(String s, int pos) {
            s = "";
            pos = s.length();
            int count = s.length();
            char[] ray;

            System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
            Scanner userInputF = new Scanner(System.in);
            s = userInputF.nextLine();

            ray = s.toCharArray();

            for (int t = 0; t < s.length(); t++) {
                System.out.println(ray[t]);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call that method yet. Try to call your method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ADSopgave2K1  intance=new ADSopgave2K1();
intance.print();
        }
```

**Edit**

```
 public void print() {

    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    Scanner userInputF = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = userInputF.nextLine();

    char[]  ray = s.toCharArray();

    for (int t = 0; t < s.length(); t++) {
        System.out.println(ray[t]);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry typo mistake, you have to pass integer parameter instead of string.

Comment: If I run it, the method print runs one time, and not the length of s

Comment: As you added `return` statement in `for loop`. why? remove it if it is not required.

Comment: But what does "test", 1 do ?

Comment: As you don't use pos and S as passed variable in method.you can remove it. see edit answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your program, Java will call `main(String[] args)`.

But this is an empty function, so you will not see any output.

Answer (score 0):

Becasue, you did not call anything in `main(String[] args)` method. Make your print method `static` and call this to your main method.

```
public static void print(String s, int pos){

}
```

**EDIT:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   print("test",1);
}
```

Comment: How do you call it in main?

Comment: @F4LLCON See my edited code. Here, in main method I call print method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your method inside main() by creating instance for your class

Answer (score 0):

```
ADSopgave2K1 r=new ADSopgave2K1();
    r.print("jai", 4);
```

Create an object of your class in side main method and then call its method.

Answer (score 0):

You should call print() method.

```
public class ADSopgave2K1 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        print("Hello World", 1);
    }

    public void print(String s, int pos) 
    {
        s = "";
        pos = s.length();
        int count = s.length();
        char[] ray;

        System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
        Scanner userInputF = new Scanner(System.in);
        s = userInputF.nextLine();

        ray = s.toCharArray();

        for (int t = 0; t < s.length(); t++) {
            System.out.println(ray[t]);
            return;
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

either you make print method static  and  call it with correct  argument 
Or
make instance of ADSopgave2K1 class and call it with correct args